# Extending Sequelize Model for Inheritance

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have build some sequelize models with strict typing extending `Model` like `Account`, `ContactData`, `Address` and so on. Since I‘m persisting roles for an `Account` and I came across Domain-Driven Design, I am going to split up my code and shift the roles away from database to Account Entity. Also splitting up the account model into several „more detailed“ models like `Admin` and `Customer`, is it possible to extend one model with like `BaseAccount` to inherit properties and methods for code reduction at all?

I've declared my Parent class like:

```
type Account = Admin | Customer | Editor | Partner;

export default class BaseAccount<T extends Account> extends Model<InferAttributes<T>, InferCreationAttributes<T>> {
    declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
    declare email: string;
    declare password: string;

    public async encryptPasswordHook(account: T) {
        const passwordHasChanged = account.changed("password");

        if (passwordHasChanged) {
            const password = account.getDataValue("password");
            const hashedPassword = await this.hashPassword(password);

            return Promise.resolve(account.setDataValue("password", hashedPassword));
        } else return;
    }
}
```

and then extending my model with BaseAccount like:

```
export default class Admin extends BaseAccount<Admin> {}
```

But this does not work since sequelized .change() method has no overload for this

Comment: TypeScript elements marked with the `declare` modifier are compiled out of the resulting JavaScript, they describe code that is already implemented elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, that's purly for typescript when using sequelize. The underlying get's filled by the init function of a model (when using sequelize-cli). Just don't know which gears to switch atm. But thanks